# How to structure a project into Object Oriented framework?

Tags: python, csv, oop, structure, system-design

I have a project and would like ideas/tips on how I could tackle it. This is the project

> Each component in a car has a number. Example:
> "Hitch" has num: "43". I want to search and return
> every car model in the database (CSV file) that has the number "43".
> In the future, I would also like to be able to see information about
> the car model. Example: "manufacturer", "HP", then info about the
> "manufacturer" etc etc.

I have never done anything like this before, but I have researched and found that maybe OOP is the way to go? In that case, how could one structure it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since your main question is how do you break your requirement into an Object Oriented framework, I would structure it as follows:

You have objects called **Parts** and an object called **Car**.
Parts will have attributes: **PartName(string)**, **PartId(integer)**, **PartManufacturer(string)**.
Car will have objects **CarName(string)**, **CarId(int)**, **CarManufacturer(string)**.

A third object **PartsInCar** will track the relation between Car and Parts.
This object will have attributes **CarPartId (int)**, **CarId(Car)**, **PartId(part)**.

Alternatively **PartsInCar** can also be an attribute of Car as a "vector of class Parts".
Depending on how granular you want to maintain the data, there is a possibility to create another class **Manufacturer** having **ManufacturerId(int)**, **ManufacturerName(string)**.

Now the question is how do you load your csv database into this structure ?
This depends on how your input data looks like.
if you are doing the whole thing in memory, then you could use `vector` or `dictionary` to store the whole "list" of parts, cars and parts_in_car.

For each class defined above you will of course need member functions that will allow us easy operation.
E.g.:

1. Cars object can have a member function that will return all Parts objects associated with it.
2. Parts object can have a member function that searches all Cars and shortlists those cars that are using this part.

Comment: This was very useful and clear. Thank you. For the CSV database question, my idea was to import with ´pandas´, then use a dictionary.

Comment: The CSV is structured like this: "Part number", "Car Models", "Part manufacturer" (e.g possibly multiple manufacturers for exhaust, tires, etc), "Preferred" (what manufacturer was preferred)

Comment: @Shesch Depending on how you are going to use this, you can even ditch the whole OOP implementation and load your csv into a pandas dataframe and just do queries on your dataframe.
It will be even simpler if the "Car Models" column in your csv does not contain multiple car names.

Comment: The "Car Models" column can contain multiple car models. It's more of a "build/spec number" than a "car model". E.g "Audi A3 Build 3" which is one specific spec. This is also why you have the "Part manufacturer" because it lists all the possible choices one had for tires etc, and the "preferred" says what was chosen.

Comment: In case you choose to go with pandas dataframes, and your CarModels looks like this:  "Audi A3 Build 3, Audi XX Build 4, Audi XX Build X", it might be a good idea to change the single string into a list of strings.

Comment: I have uploaded an image to better illustrate the structure.

Comment: 'Pandas' is not a must. Just an initial idea I had because I have used it previously to import CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dictionary with the key being the car name, and the value being a list of information about each car. You can assign certain aspects of the car to each index of the list to keep track of the data. you could use oop for this but it's a bit uncessary if I understood your question correctly